# Insert Attchements by Site User - INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

Tags: force.com-sites, guest-user

I am tring to insert attachements by setting a Custom Object Id as the ParentId. Operation is done as the Guest User(on a Site). Custom object has the necessary permission for the Guest User profile.
It is a simple Attachement list insert,

```
        List<Attachment> attachmentList = new List<Attachment>();
        Blob pageData;
        for(Id orderId : orderMap.keySet()) {
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
            String urlString = '/apex/CC_InvoiceSalesOrderPDF';
            Blob pageData = CC_Utility.getPDFFileContent(orderId, urlString);
            attachment.ParentId = orderId;
            attachment.Description = 'Invoice ' + orderId;
            attachment.Body = pageData;
            attachment.Name = 'InvoiceSaleOrder-' + order.Id + '.pdf';
            attachmentList.add(attachment);
        }
        
        insert attachmentList;
```

But I am getting the following error while trying to insert the attachement list

> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

The operation completes successfully if I do the insert as internal user.

Is it possible to insert attachements by Site user? If yes, Would there be a way to overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi,Can you please double check if you have the access on Order Object for guest user profile on which you are trying to attach the file.If not,I would request you to provide the access level since we are trying to access the Order Object with the external user.

Comment: @ShirishaPathuri Actually the access is granted using a sharing rule. 
Group: Portal Users -> Read/Write. Guest user is editing the order without any issue. But I am getting this problem while trying to insert the Attachments on that order record. I am wondering if Attachement creation is possible for Guest users?

Comment: Is the setting allow guest users to upload files checked in community administration?

Answer (score -1):

By default guest users will not be able to upload files.We need to enable the permission called "Allow site guest users to upload files" which will allow the guest user to upload files.To enable, go to Setup > General Settings, and select Allow site guest users to upload files.

Please refer the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_networks_guest_upload.htm) for the same.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Shirisha, Thank you for the comment. But this settings is already enabled

Comment: This enabled you to upload a file using component lightning:fileUpload  but not from Apex Class